# Weak convergence counter-example

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, weak-convergence

Given probability measures $\mu,\mu_n: \mathcal{B}(X)\to R$. Construct an example such that $$\langle f,\mu_n\rangle \rightarrow \langle f,\mu\rangle$$
for all convex function $f:X\to R$ but $\mu_n$ does not converge weakly to $\mu$.

This question is from a problem in a Partially Observed Markov Decision Process. In there we can guarantee that starting from any initial prior $\pi$, for all cost function the ACOE has a bounded solution, which implies that $E[v(\pi_n)\mid\pi_0=\pi] \rightarrow C$. But the expected cost function $v(\pi)$ can only be a certain convex function of $\pi$ even if we allow all kind of cost function. So I wonder whether or not there's a counter-example saying that convex test function $f$ is not enough for weak convergence.

The POMDP average cost problem is from this paper: http://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/0318028